# Compiling with different flags in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a single program used to interact with a joystick. It uses conditional compilation to specify a specific joystick. We do this right now by just hard coding the correct flag into the Makefile.

I'd like to make it so it uses a different flag based on the command given to the Makefile. So for example, I currently have this:

```
.PHONY: saitek
saitek: $(SOURCES)
    $(COMPILE) -DSAITEK
.PHONY: logitech
logitech: $(SOURCES)
    $(COMPILE) -DLOGITECH
```

I want only one of these commands to ever be run, and I want them all to make the same executable. But if I rerun 'make' it will compile the program again. I'd like it to recognize that it's already built the program.

Is there anyway to do this with a Makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNUMake, this will do what you're asking. It uses a different flag based on the command given to Make, and it doesn't rebuild the program unnecessarily.

```
.PHONY: saitek logitech
saitek: JOYSTICK=SAITEK
logitech: JOYSTICK=LOGITECH

# Suppose the actual name of your executable is "program"

saitek logitech: program

program: $(SOURCES)
    $(COMPILE) -D$(JOYSTICK)
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU make [inherits variables from its environment](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/make/make.html#SEC66), so if you specify

```
$ JOYSICK=LOGITECH
```

in your shell, and use

```
CFLAGS+=-D$(JOYSTICK)
```

in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I question the necessity of this. You could just call `make` as something like `make CFLAGS=-DSAITEK` or use `autoconf` and substitute in the correct defines.

That said, how about something like this:

```
saitek logitech: program
.PHONY: saitek logitech

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),saitek)
CFLAGS += -DSAITEK
endif
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),logitech)
CFLAGS += -DLOGITECH
endif

program: $(OBJS)
# Whatever
```